# C++ Reading a string from socket that contains null character before the end

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a socket server (written in c++) that receives tcp messages, these messages are data that have been deflated.

Due to the deflation(compression) method these messages may contain "null" (0) character.

An example repersentation of the data (with chars converted to int and seperated by comma):

> 141, 208, 59, 10, 128, 80, 12, 68, 209, 222, 197, 72, 94, 94, 190,
>   100, 55, 246, 86, 238, 31, 212, 82, 81, 50, 76, 49, 205, 169, 238,
>   182, 31, 75, 114, 13, 73, 37, 158, 162, 90, 170, 171, 120, 90, 197,
>   117, 164, 81, 116, 239, 97, 162, 55, 54, **0**, 35, 128, 241, 222, 56,
>   1, 102, 2, 198, **0**, 147, 189, 9, 6, 12, 208, 57, 128, 206, 249,
>   238, 236, 31, 70, **0**, 227, 173, 81, 34, 192, 76, 192, 24, 96, 178,
>   55, 131, 127, 204, 9, **0**

As you can see in the above example "null" (0) is represented before the actual end.

So when using:

```
message_size = read( client, buffer, 4096 )
```

The read is returned at the first "null" (0).

Is it possible to continue reading so that i receive the whole message?

Or is there some kind of magic trick to be done here?

EDIT: Using Linux Centos (2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64)

Comment: while read returns > 0, keep reading?

Comment: I've tried what your suggesting Gill Bates but the issue still persists. Only the first part of the message gets received.

Comment: Please clarify _exactly_ which `read()` function you are using.

Comment: @Alnitak im using this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html
My server basically does this: socket() -> bind() -> listen() -> accept() -> read().

Comment: As said below, that function does not stop on NUL.

Comment: @GillBates Odd, I can see that it is specifically the messages that contain null that fails. Sometimes these messages does not have null in them and these i receive just fine.

Comment: You will need to create a [mcve]

Comment: are you perhaps using the C family of string functions to convert that buffer into a (NUL terminated) string?

Comment: @Alnitak I was using strncat, this seem to have been the issue. Thanks

Comment: great - I've added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `read()` function doesn't care about NUL characters, it seems likely to me that you're passing the buffer into one of the original C standard string functions, which use NUL terminated strings.

The C++ `std::string` does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to continue reading so that i receive the whole message?

Yes. Use *Unformatted Input* functions. An *Unformatted Input* function will not stop at the termination character.

Edit: It appears that you are using the POSIX `read` function rather than a C++ API. As it happens, POSIX `read` doesn't stop on the terminator either.

Comment: I think OP was referring to doing something with `read` only.

Comment: @GillBates `std::basic_istream::read` is an Unformatted Input function. It does not stop at the terminator.

Comment: I'm sure op is talking about [this `read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

Comment: @GillBates which _doesn't_ stop on NUL characters

Comment: @GillBates I see. The question didn't mention POSIX nor Linux so I wouldn't be sure. That said, it doesn't stop at terminator either.

Comment: Indeed, which is why the question is odd.

Comment: Your final sentence in your edit doesn't always apply (although for the OP it's relevant).  For UDP socket, the `read` will be chunked by whole packets.

Answer (score 0):

AS mentioned by @Alnitak i was using a C family of string functions, this is what caused the odd behaviour.

I used strncat().
I have now resolved the issue by looping through my buffer received by read, and then appending it to a std::string with push_back().